# Set Differences of Folders A and B ie |A-B| = C

Tags: linux, bash, shell

How can I get a set of the difference of files in folder `A` that are not in folder `B`, this should be output to folder `C`. I other words `C` would contain all the files that do not exist in `B` but exist in `A`? Is there a chain command in linux?

Comment: BTW, your home page http://ethanlim.net/ seems inaccessible today july 13th 2015.

Comment: yup sorry for revamping it in the meantime... thanks for notifying though :-)

Answer (score 2):

You might use the [diff(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/diff.1.html) command, perhaps as `diff -Naur`. BTW, [patch(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/patch.1.html) is handy too..

But you really want some version control system (a.k.a. [revision control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control)). Learn more about [git](http://git-scm.com/). I strongly recommend you to use it, even for personal small projects.

Later, you might consider publishing some (perhaps most) of your code as [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software), e.g. on [github](http://github.com/)

Comment: knew diff had something but you beat me to the punch :)

Comment: no no I have two folders with images, B has images which I have copied and paste to before. A are all the images which I have from my camera. B contains some images from A. I wanna know which those images in A but not in B, a set difference actually.

Comment: AFAIK, `diff` will say something on binary files like images.

Answer (score 2):

May not be perfect. Try this:

```
(ls -1 A 2>/dev/null && ls -1 B 2>/dev/null) | sort | uniq -u | xargs -I REPLACE cp A/REPLACE C
```

Comment: Note that this would fail for (a corner case of) filenames containing newline. A quick fix would be to use `find` instead of `ls` with `-maxdepth 1 -print0` & then `-z` option for `sort` & `uniq` & `-0` for `xargs`.

Comment: You can also use `... | sort -u | ...` instead of `... | sort | uniq | ...`

Comment: sort -u can replace uniq but not uniq -u. We need the ones that do not repeat. you are right about file names containing new line; I have never come across such a file anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

Would the rsync command be useful?  If you run it with

```
--dry-run
```

it would report how it would make one directory the same as the other, without actually changing anything.